# XAML - Referencing another assemblies resources, without adding the assembly as a reference

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two Assemblies in the same folder, AssemblyOne and AssemblyTwo. I'm trying to use the resources file in AssemblyOne within AssemblyTwo but am unable to add a direct reference to my references list in AssemblyTwo due to a circuilar dependency if I do.

I have tried things such as this in AssemblyTwo;

```
 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyOne;component/Properties/Resources.resx" />
```

And even a direct link to the file itself;

```
 <ResourceDictionary Source="..\..\AssemblyOne\Properties\Resources.resx" />
```

Both were unsuccesfull, the former returns the error;

```
Assembly 'AssemblyOne' is not referenced in this project.
```

As expect as it isn't referenced, and the latter returns the error that it cannot find the path specified.

Is there a way to do what I'm after. Sorry if my explanation is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You could [add the file as a link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306234) to AssemblyOne and use it like an internal resource.  This maintains one source of the file but both projects use it.  This is a bit more of an "easy way out" to the problem.

**Option 2 (*Preferred*):**

Simply create a new project (say, Assembly.Shared) with the shared resources in it, and reference the new project or the .dll in both AssemblyOne and AssemblyTwo. This is a general solution to many circular dependency cases.  You can do this to share code, resources, etc.

Comment: Which of these would be less of a resource hog would you say, I'd like to think option 1 would be the better way if it's the only Assembly that needs access to the resources outside of the main assembly itself.

Comment: I'd imagine it to be a negligible.  Practically the only difference between the two would be how you maintain them.  If you end up with more shared resources then that is more links to manage, whereas you would only be managing one central reference with the assembly.  I'd say give both a shot - or start with the link and if you want to change to the assembly later you can.

Comment: Feels like that might be the best way to do it, working with quite a large system presently and would require changing quite a few things to work with a shared assembly instead of just the link, will definitely keep that in my mind for future scope though, thanks a ton.